# <object> tag with svg and (double)click events

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I have some object tags that each embeds a svg file.
Clicking on the object tag (the svg), should call a javascript function. As I understand, the object tag doesn't support mouse events.

I have read of dousins solutions with object & flash, but they don't work with svg.

It is *not* a solution to code something in the svg file.

Comment: Have you found a workaround? I'm facing the same trouble: "document" do not receive click event if an `<object>` tag is clicked. I'm forced to use `<object>` because I'm loading external SVG, and I can't use `<img>` because I modify those them (color, stroke, etc).

Answer (score 2):

You could perhaps use an <img> tag instead, if you don't need scripting and interactivity inside the svg file.

It's like Robert Longson says, the mouse events go into the <object> tag, so you'll need to put your event handlers in the svg instead (you can do this with script, and without needing to modify the original svg file). [Here's an example](http://xn--dahlstrm-t4a.net/svg/html/get-embedded-svg-document-script.html) of how to access the DOM of the svg from the html that references it.

To clarify:

- get the root svg element (see the [example](http://xn--dahlstrm-t4a.net/svg/html/get-embedded-svg-document-script.html))
- call `rootsvg.addEventListener("click", window.parent.yourFunctionHere, false)` (assuming `yourFunctionHere` is a function defined in a script in the main html document)

Comment: The img tag is not a solution, as I need to warn people that can not see the svg. AFAIK, this can only be done with the <object> tag. The other solution doesn't work either.

Comment: You can warn people in many ways, e.g using http://modernizr.com, and replacing the svgs with pngs for when svg isn't supported.

Comment: That would require imagemagick, which the fewest people have installed on their server. But is there an easier way to detect svg support than installing a separate script for it?

Comment: You can extract the part from modernizr that detects svg support, which is IIRC just a single line of javascript code. And if you only wanted to show a warning then you could just replace the <object> tags with that warning for example.

Answer (score 1):

You CAN use an img tag, and still edit an SVG using the document model.  All it takes is a bit of thought.  I have been working on a similar problem, where svg text needed to be editable, and so I needed a mouseclick to activate the editing.

If you want your SVGs to be clickable, the object tag is NOT the way to go.  It reroutes all the events to its content, and placing a transparent div on top of it is not possible, as the object automatically becomes the top item, so that the object you are embedding can always receive the mouse events. (think flash video player).

What you can do is convert your svgs using the XMLSerializer and createObjectURL into blobs, which can then be displayed as img tags, using the following, where mysvg is an SVG which has been loaded and parsed as an xml document with xhttp :

```
     var mysvg = xhttp.responseXML;
     var xml2str = new XMLSerializer();
     var svg_blob = new Blob([xml2str.serializeToString(mysvg)],{'type': "image/svg+xml"});
     var url = URL.createObjectURL(svg_blob);
     document.getElementById("svg1").src = url;
```

svg1 is an img tag, which will happily take any event handlers you wish to use.

Answer (score 0):

mouse events go to the contents of the `<object>` tag.

You're going to need to put some other tag like an absolutely positioned transparent `<div>` in front of the `<object>` tag and use that to catch mouse events.

Alternatively you could set the contents of the `<object>` tag to be pointer-events="none" so that they don't handle events, at which point you can handle them in the `<object>` tag.

Comment: I still need to use some hover events on the SVG file. Besides, positioning the div to absolute, will give me some layout issues. I have tried your solution, but couldn't get it to work.